# jshint complains about shorthand AND operator with boolean

Tags: javascript, operators, jshint, shorthand-if

I've got a javascript function that needs to be executed based on a boolean value. I really like to use the `&&` operator for this (which only executes the second part if the first results in `true`).

```
someBoolean && executeFunction();
```

However, when JSHint checks my code, I get the following message:

> Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.

I'm wondering why JSHint throws this message. I know I can easily avoid it by using a simple **if** statement, but I really like the simplicity of this one. Maybe I need to fiddle a bit with some JSHint configuration? Is there some hidden danger in this line of code?

Comment: JSHint only throws a warning, so is this really an issue? I don't see directly how you could remove it since `var x = someBoolean && executeFunction();` throws another warning: the fact that `x` is unused. I also don't really see some hidden dangers here... (but one never does until the bug appears ^^)

Comment: @reverse_engineer Yeah, but on this project I'm unable to build the distribution files when the JSHint parser gives any warning or error. It is a bit strict but it saves us a lot of trouble in the end. I'm probably forced to make it an if statement.

Comment: I see, yeah too bad that JSHint complains about `expr;` like this... In this case it's useful code, and if it's not useful, I suppose all JS engines will remove it anyway (at least if it's in hot code).